# Dagger 2: Dependency Inheritance Hierarchy

Tags: java, android, inheritance, dependency-injection, dagger-2

So, the way things are setup for my project is there is one `BaseActivityComponent` and one `BaseActivityModule` that serves a `BaseActivity` class which all activities inherit from.

What if there was a case where I'll have an activity `SpecialActivity extends BaseActivity` that needs a bunch of dependencies injected to it specifically **in addition to** the dependencies injected to it from `BaseActivity`

How should this situation be treated?

Comment: you will have to declare `SpecialActivity` as `@ContributesAndroidInjector` regardless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I made a GitHub project with a pretty lengthy breakdown on how things should work to solve this inheritance problem I presented above: https://github.com/Obaied/BareBonesAndroidDagger

Please feel free to give feedback